# Thunderbird freezing

Tags: thunderbird

I can open Thunderbird but as soon as I click on any file thunderbird freezes. Went to tools can see first page of settings but thunderbird freezes.  Ran norton 360 & rebooted too

Went to firefox website to download thunderbird Version 3.1.9 (3) program downloads and then freezes while norton checks for viruses....

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Try disabling *Global Search and Indexing*. You can disable it by accessing Options/Preferences ([*Tools > Options* on Windows, *Edit > Preferences* on Linux](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Menu_differences_in_Windows%2C_Linux%2C_and_Mac)) then clicking *Advanced*. The *Global Search and Indexing* option is under the *General* tab.

I had the same problem for a long time. I wasn't able to fix it by re-installing Thunderbird, creating a new profile, and even re-installing my OS (for a different reason).

Comment: Thanks! That's the first time I've come across advice that actually makes a difference to this infuriating behaviour from Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Norton while downloading a new copy of Thunderbird, and install it.  Test it while Norton is still disabled.